# Allow the use of the tag [feather]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-creation-request

[Feather](https://blog.rstudio.org/2016/03/29/feather/) is a relatively new file format to store dataframes. There are currently a couple of questions asked about it ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39530240/error-while-reading-with-feather-package), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37441185/error-invalid-file-is-too-small-to-be-a-well-formed-file-error-when-using-fe), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38271025/how-to-save-file-in-feather-format-storage-from-spark), [4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36407629/unable-to-write-my-dataframe-using-feather-strided-data-not-supported), [5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37445984/shiny-with-feather-and-reactivefilereader-not-working) and so on) but I cannot create a new tag because there is another tag with a similar name ([feathers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/feathers)):

> You are attempting to create the tag [feather]; however the tag
>   [feathers] already exists! If you think this new tag should be
>   allowed, raise it on meta.

Can we create this new tag?

Comment: [feather**s**] has only 4 questions that are about [feather**js**] or [feather**ui**]. So I guess [feather**s**] could be burninated, and clear the way for [feather].

Comment: And no tag wiki for feathers.  It looks like a javascript framework, so maybe it's better to rename the other to `feathers.js` or something?

Comment: You might want to consider using `feature-format` or something qualified. It seems that using the first half of some other library causes more mis-tags than not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's what I'd recommend:

- <s>Replace all usages of [feathers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/feathers) with [feathersjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/feathersjs)</s> (Done)
- Create the [feather](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/feather) tag to capture the file system
- **Add a description to the new feather tag** to indicate its usage

Comment: There's also [tag:feathersui].

Comment: Thanks. I've created the tag and suggested a tag excerpt.